# Generic way to test performance/efficiency of some code?

Tags: java, performance

Can anybody tell me of a way that one can determine the efficiency of a program that i have written, that is not specific to a particular computer. For instance a piece of code running on an i3 may take 1 second, but on an i7 it may take 0.95 seconds. Then if you test the program again if the computer is doing just a little more work the times may increase to 1.0001 and 0.950003 respectively. I want a way to measure efficiency in a way that would be the same on all archs. Is that (mathematically,...,) possible?

Comment: You could measure CPU clock cycles. Unforunately I don't know how that's done in Java.

Comment: hard to understand what you really want.  you may determine the order of magnitude of the effort and express that in Big-O notation - or you may just take some timings. understanding how much effect other computer load will have will be very tricky

Comment: Not really, in real life the time taken almost never scales in a nice continuous way with the input size. Cache effects in particular often cause one or more big discontinuations. What you often see to characterize the real life performance of something is a scatterplot on a log-log scale, or a just a line on a log-log scale.

Answer (score 1):

> I want a way to measure efficiency in a way that would be the same on all archs

You wont get exactly the same number on the same machine, running at the same CPU speed with the same code and the same version of Java.

You can't hope to get a number which will be the same across architectures, with different versions of Java, CPUs, speed, loads, OSes.

In short, your question is not possible on any real machine.  Only a theoretical one which is why big-O is for a theoretical machine (and is derived from the code, not measured)

Comment: i did not remember the old big O(Asymptotic notation or Order of growth, for those who don't know).